# Error: *** Deployment Failed *** -- Invalid number of parameters for "undefined". Got 0 expected 1!

Tags: solidity, truffle, blockchain, truffle-test, visual-studio-code

I am trying to deploy my smart contract. Upon deployment, I get this error message.
[image]

Here is my contractToken.sol

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.2;

contract BPToken {
    uint256 public totalSupply; 

    mapping(address => uint256) public balanceOf;


    constructor(uint256 _initialSupply) public { //constructor
        totalSupply = _initialSupply;
    }
}
```

Here is my Token.js:

```
const { equal } = require("assert");

var BPToken = artifacts.require("./BPToken.sol")

    contract('BPToken', function(accounts) {
    
        var tokenInstance;

        it('sets the total supply upon deployment', function() {
        return BPToken.deployed().then(function(instance) {
            tokenInstance = instance;
            return tokenInstance.totalSupply();
        }).then(function(totalSupply) {
            assert.strictEqual(totalSupply.toNumber(), 1000000, 'sets the total supply to 1,000,000');
            return tokenInstance.balanceOf(accounts[0]);
        }); then(function(adminBalance) {
            assert.strictEqual(adminBalance, toNumber(), 1000000, "It allocates the initial supply to the admin account.")
        
        }
        
        );
    });

});
```

Here's my deployment:

```
const BPToken = artifacts.require("./BPToken.sol");

module.exports = function(deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(BPToken);
};
```

Would like some help in addressing what this error occurrence means, I'm new to Truffle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the migration script you need to pass the constructor parameters when deploying the contract.

In this case there's one parameter `uint256 _initialSupply`. So passing the initialSupply should fix the problem. For example setting it to `1000000` tokens can be done like this (due to javascript's number precision you should use strings for make it work).

```
module.exports = function(deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(BPToken, "1000000");
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I also have a deployment error.I resolve it by deleting unnecessary smart contracts.
You should try this.